# User can access folder which has Explicit Allow but Inherited Deny (Group)

Tags: permissions, domain, ntfs

I have a folder `bar` in domain server, and want to share to user `p_an`.
I set this permission to this folder as `p_an` can modify `bar` folder (Read, List, Write).

=> Explicit Allow

But `bar` folder is contains in `foo`, which deny the group which `p_an` is in.

=> Inherited Deny (Group)

[image: Inherited Deny]

By the hierarchy of precedence

> Explicit Deny.
>
> Explicit Allow.
>
> Inherited Deny.
>
> Inherited Allow.

The `Explicit Allow` is take over `Inherited Deny`, and p_an can access `bar`, but it can't.
Error given :

> Windows cannot access xxxxx
>
> You do not have permission to access xxxxx. Contact your network administrator to request access

To make sure, I've checked Effective Access of `p_an` user
[image]

So why this error happen?

Comment: Effective access does not calculate the Share permissions. What are the Share permissions on the shared folder?

Comment: @joeqwerty It's 'Allow - Everyone - Full control'